# unable to create multiple UIImageView in loop ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to show no. of images in different image view. if i have 3 image then i want show in 3 diff. UIImageView in my View. Here is my code that only shows one image. What have i missed here?

```
NSArray * _thumbnails = _claimReport.photos.allObjects;
    if (_thumbnails.count >0)
        {
            NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i =1; i<_thumbnails.count; i++)
            {
                UIImageView *newImageViews = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 1700*i+20, 670, 700)];
                LAPhoto *photo = [_thumbnails objectAtIndex:i];

                [newImageViews  setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:photo.photo]];
                NSLog(@" newImageViews %@ ",newImageViews);
                [imageViews addObject:newImageViews];
               [self.formView addSubview:newImageViews];
            }

            NSLog(@"Count %d" , imageViews.count);
        }
```

Comment: it is created imageviews but check your frame " (40, 1700*i+20, 670, 700)" y value is ' 1700*i+20' it is beyond the device.

Comment: Vineesh TP . whats the max height we can have. i have to add long images totalling around a height of 8000 px. is the code looks fine? its for iPad.

Comment: if 4 inch device then max height is 568 and if 3.5 inch device then max height is 480, and for both max width is 320.

Comment: loop should be start from zero not 1 its not creating imageview for first element of your array and you have to check imageview frame.

Comment: you were not increase the Y in after the loop

Comment: Max height of iPhone is 568pix only you have to add height is 8000, check how much it is far away from the device.
If you want, addSubview imageview on scrollview, based on the imageview size set contentSize of scrollView.

Comment: You should also set either i to 0 (i = 0) or to _thumbnails.count (i <= _thumbnails.count) as your loop limits. You are currently attempting to make (_thumbnails.count - 2) UIImageView(s)

Comment: if your image is big height then you should use scroll view and then  add UIImage object.

Comment: thanks all. @Vineesh so there is no any way ..right?

Comment: @LUI : just think about user side. Device height is 568, to view the image how much he have to scroll. I think this is not a good !dea.

Comment: @LUI: If you want you can add  on scrollview.

Comment: Vineesh TP .user has agreed on this. They need a word doc. add on scrollView means [_scrollView addsubview:newImageViews]; ?

Comment: are you want  to display a word document?

Comment: nope..just kind of.a long view containing lots of images and text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the images in a scroll view:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.formView addSubview:self.scrollView];

NSArray * _thumbnails = _claimReport.photos.allObjects;
if (_thumbnails.count >0)
{
    NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i =0; i<_thumbnails.count; i++)
    {
            UIImageView *newImageViews = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 800*i+20, 670, 700)];
            LAPhoto *photo = [_thumbnails objectAtIndex:i];

        [newImageViews  setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:photo.photo]];
        NSLog(@" newImageViews %@ ",newImageViews);
        [imageViews addObject:newImageViews];
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(670, 800 *i + 800);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:newImageViews];
    }

    NSLog(@"Count %d" , imageViews.count);
}
```